# A value in x_new is above/below interpolation range

Tags: arrays, numpy, interpolation

Here's my code. I keep getting that error, no matter if I use inside_sig_r or inside_sig_r2. If I take out the last line I don't get this error.  Thanks for any help.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate, interpolate
from math import sqrt,pi,cos,sin,exp

rho = 2.78e11 * .3
delta = 1.68

def M(r):
    return ((4*pi)/3)*(r**3)*rho

def R(M):
    return (( 3 * M) / (4 * pi * rho)) ** (.3333)

def W(x):
    return 3.*(sin(x) - x*cos(x))/(x**3.)

data = np.loadtxt("//Users//Slemons//Downloads//pk2.dat", float)
k_data = (10**data[:,0])
Pk_data = (10**data[:,1])



Pk = interpolate.interp1d(k_data,Pk_data,kind='cubic')

Masses = np.arange(1e10,1e16,1e10)
r_from_M = np.array(map(R,Masses),float)

print r_from_M[0]

def inside_sig_r(k,r):
    return ((W(k*r)**2.) * Pk(k) * (k**2.)) / (2. * (pi ** 2.))
def inside_sig_r2(z,r):
    k = (1.+z)/(1.-z)
    return inside_sig_r(k,r) *2./(1.-z)**2.

sigma_r = lambda k : sqrt(integrate.quad(inside_sig_r,.4,np.inf,args=(k)))

sigr = np.array(map(sigma_r,Masses),float)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not really a standalone code, since I can't see your data in '//Users//Slemons//Downloads//pk2.dat'. However, the error is quite specific - the data produced by inside_sig_r(2) are above or below the range you supplied (0.4, np.inf). You should either change the range or make sure that the functions return values inside this range.